# DD-WRT limited connection on WPA2/AES

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I installed DD-WRT on a TP-Link TL-WR740N router with the dynamic DHCP WAN setting enabled. Wireless settings are as below:

```
Basic Settings 
    wireless mode : AP
    wireless network mode : mixed or 802.n only (which is better)
    channel width : full
    wireless channel : auto 

Wireless security 
    Security mode : WPA2 Personal
    Encryption : AES
```

Using Ethernet, I can access the Internet and everything works fine.

When I'm setting security mode `none` (no security) everything is working but on the laptop's WiFi, it displays "*limited connectivity*". The laptop can't get an IP from the router.

Where does the problem lie?

Comment: Well, do you by any chance have entered wrong password?

Comment: no i'm entering right password if it was wrong then laptop can't even connect... but in this case laptop is connecting but getting "limited Access"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine after re-installing dd-wrt.

May be some bug in the version.